# Conversion issue of long long to unsigned long

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Hi I'm beginner in Objective. I am converting Video file to NSData. It's work fine but it give me Value conversion issue with a message "implicit conversion loses integer precision:long long to unsigned long"
Here is code

```
long long DataSize = [alassetRep size];
Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(DataSize);
NSUInteger buffered = (NSUInteger)[alassetRep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:alassetRep.size error:nil];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
```

The prolem is here **Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(DataSize);** and **length:alassetRep.size** What should I do? Anybody....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare DataSize as `unsigned long`. The problem is that regardless of the return type of `[alassetRep size]` you need to use an `unsigned long` when using `malloc` because that's the data type it expects.

```
unsigned long DataSize = [alassetRep size];
```

Comment: Thank you it work for me. but I have brought little more changes in your answer. like **"unsigned long DataSize = (unsigned long)[alasserRep size];"**